# How to detect "Hand" in a card drawing game

Tags: c#, algorithm, probability

Having an array which represents a 5 picked card out of a full deck (52 cards).
So a random hand will look like this ['H3','H6','D3','D4','S4'], (here is h 2 pairs 4 and 3).
I'm looking for a way to know this properties about the random 5 cards:

- What hand name is it. i.e:"Four of a kind","Three of a kind" and so
  on.
- What is the probability of that hand, taking in mind that it is a
  perfect random.
- I can choose the data structure
- I use c#

Comment: You need to know what poker hands there are and how your data structure represents cards? Then take a 500 or 600 level college probability math class (or look it up on wikipedia).

Comment: Looks like you were dealt two-pair - fours and threes.

Comment: The hand is an array of what? Of strings? Of something else? Are you free to choose the data structure? Is that something you are asking (what it should be) or is the data structure already given? Is there a specific programming language used?

Comment: @AndersForsgren Yes I can choose the data structure, I prefer to work with c# / javascript .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set up some data structures to represent suits, ranks, cards and hands. there are numerous ways to do this for good performance, e.g. using bit vectors, but assume we want to make it readable: make enums for suits and ranks, and a struct for cards, and a class for a hand. By the way, this type of example is where you wish you were [using F#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43831/poker-hands-kata-in-f).

Note: code is for illustration purposes only: it has never seen a compiler. Don't expect to paste this & run.

```
enum Suit { Spades, Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs }
enum Rank { Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, 
            Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace }

enum HandType { Nothing, Pair, TwoPair, ThreeOfAKind, Straight,
     Flush, FullHouse, FourOfAKind, StraightFlush }    

public struct Card 
{
   public Suit Suit { get; private set; }
   public Rank Rank { get; private set; }
   public Card(Rank rank, Suit suit)
   {
      Suit = suit;
      Rank = rank;
   }     
}

public class Hand 
{
   public IReadOnlyList<Card> Cards { get; private set };
   public Hand(IEnumerable<Card> cards) 
   { 
      this.Cards = cards.OrderByDescending(c => c.Rank).ToList(); 
   }   
}
```

The evaluation can be done in a method that takes in a hand and returns the kind of hand. Note that this only *classifies* the hand, it doesn't actually figure out the complete rank, such that a higher straight beats a lower and so on. I have left out the actual implementation, but here is a skeleton:

```
public static class HandEvaluator
{
    public static HandType GetHandType(Hand hand)
    {           
       bool isFlush = hand.Cards.Distinct(c => c.Suit).Count() == 1;
       bool isStraight = // five consecutive ranks. Mind the wheel straight Ace->5! 
       if (isStraight && isFlush)
         return HandType.StraightFlush;           

       // group cards by rank, then find the group count & sizes
       var groups = hand.Cards.GroupBy(c => c.Rank);

       if (/* max group size = 4 */)
          return HandType.FourOfAKind;
       if (/* two groups and max group size = 3 */)
          return HandType.FullHouse;
       if (isFlush)
         return HandType.Flush;
       if (isStraight)
         return HandType.Straight;   
       if (/* three groups and max group size 3 */)
          return HandType.ThreeOfAKind;

       // ... And so on for two pair, pair. 

       return HandType.Nothing;
    }
}
```

As for the probabilities of different hands: those you should be able to do on paper easier than with a program, but once you have a classifying program, you can easily get the statistics by generating all possible hands, classifying them, and grouping/counting the result by the evaluated handtype.

Answer (score 4):

Identifying a hand is easy once you take into account that there is a hierarchy based on value. So although a straight flush is also a flush and a full house is also two pairs, you'll always choose the classification that is worth more.

This means that if you check your five cards against the criteria of each hand in descending order of value, the first one matching will be correct. (Something like a [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) could be extremely useful here.)

As for the probabilities, I'd just [look them up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability). (Mind you, a full deck is 52 cards not 54.)

Comment: If I can choose the data structure what is the best choice to make ? in regarding to be able to calculate the probability and hand name .

Comment: @HaddarMacdasi Whatever you feel comfortable with. I'd probably use a class containing two enum-type fields, one for suit and one for rank. And once again, there's no point calculating the probabilities, they're already well-known and have a simple closed formula.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the probabilities of having each hand, it is a simple counting problem that takes into consideration that there are 52 choose 5 = 2,598,960 distinct hands, so that you just need to count how many hands qualify for each type of hand and divide it by 2598960.

For example there are 4 distinct royal flushes -> chance of 4/2,598,960=0.000153907%

There are 4*10=40 distinct straight flushes -> chance of 40/2,598,960=0.00153907%

There are 13*48=624 distinct quads -> chance of 624/2,598,960=0.024009603%

And so on..

If you don't like counting problems you could use your program to enumerate these  2,598,960 hands and count how many flushes, quads and so on.

Regarding the code to detect the hand - I would store the hand in sorted order (according to the rank/height of the card, ignoring the suit i.e.  ['H3','D3','D4','S4','H6']). This will help you detect pairs, two pairs, triplets, quads, full houses and straights very efficiently.
Detecting flush is very easy - just check if all five cards are from the same suit. And you are done!